# Determining partial derivatives from the set of implicit equations.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I have a function
$$\vec{y} = F(\vec{p},\vec{x})$$
where $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^6$ and $\vec{p} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Derivatives of $F$ are not known but there are relationships inside $\vec{y}$:

$$p_1 y_1 = y_2 y_4$$
$$p_2 y_1 y_3 = y_5$$
$$p_3 y_1 y_4 = y_6$$

And I want to determine all the partial derivatives $\frac{\displaystyle\partial{y_i}}{\displaystyle\partial{p_j}}$.

My attempt:

For y's, which are in direct relationship with $p_j$ i rewrite the condition to explicit form, eg. $$y_2 = \frac{\displaystyle p_1 y_1}{\displaystyle y_4}$$
thus
$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial{y_2}}{\displaystyle\partial{p_1}} = \frac{\displaystyle y_1}{\displaystyle y_4}$$

and when there is no direct relationship, i combine two or more conditions:
$$y_1 = \frac{\displaystyle y_6}{\displaystyle p_3 y_4}$$

$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial{y_2}}{\displaystyle\partial{p_3}} = \frac{\displaystyle\partial}{\displaystyle\partial{p_3}}(\frac{\displaystyle p_1 y_1}{\displaystyle y_4}) = \frac{\displaystyle\partial}{\displaystyle\partial{p_3}}(\frac{\displaystyle p_1 y_6}{\displaystyle p_3 y_4^2}) = -\frac{\displaystyle p_1 y_6}{\displaystyle p_3^2 y_4^2}$$

Is this correct? I don't feel sure with this.
Please, correct me if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is more convinient to use total differentiation such as
$$p_1 y_1 - y_2 y_4=0 \Rightarrow dp_1y_1+p_1dy_1-dy_2y_4-y_2dy_4=0$$
Taking a partial derivative means that you have to take all other variables as fixed. In above example if you fix $y_2$ and $y_4$ it follows that $dy_2=0$ and $dy_4=0$
$$\Rightarrow dp_1y_1+p_1dy_1-0\,y_4-y_2\,0=0\Rightarrow \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial p_1}=-\frac{y_1}{p_1}$$
$$\text{by fixing $y_1$ and $y_4$}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial p_1}=\frac{y_1}{y_4}$$
$$\text{by fixing $y_1$ and $y_2$}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial y_4}{\partial p_1}=\frac{y_1}{y_2}$$
And by repeating this steps in all relations you can eliminate (or find explicit solutions for) all the partial derivatives wrt $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$.

Comment: this means that eg. $\frac{\displaystyle\partial{y_2}}{\displaystyle\partial{p_3}}$ is allways zero.

Comment: That's right. $\frac{\partial{y_2}}{\partial{p_3}}=\frac{\partial{y_3}}{\partial{p_3}}= \frac{\partial y_5}{\partial p_3}=0$.

Comment: but if I inject the first equation to the third, i can get e.g $p_3 y_2  = p_1 y_6 y_4^{-2}$ which is valid and I can obtain $dp_3 y_2 + p_3 dy_2 = 0$ from which I can get $\frac{dy_2}{dp_3} = -\frac{y_2}{p_3}$ which is in contradiction with the previous fact, that it is zero...

Comment: That is not a contradiction, you are just changing variables. In original case you say the third equation depends on $y_1$ explicitly; but by using injection you are eliminating $y_1$ and introducing a new relation. Both ways are valid.

Comment: OK. In fact, I want to obtain $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial p_3}$ as $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial p_3}$ where $F_2$ is fragment of the $F$ which returns only $y_2$ for some constant $x$, where I don't know the derivative. This means, that knowing only few relations between p's and y's is not enough to have single derivative. I can deduce from the system also few other relations, but since they are still not enough to calculate y's from x's and p's, I'll never get the real derivatives.